# Why a model works different as a FMU and as a model?

Tags: python, openmodelica

I'm having a recurrent problem with the implementation of FMU on Python. I've created them in OpenModelica and they work just fine when I simulate them. But when I import them to Python the output results are different!
I have tried several ways to localize the problem but I can't seem to find it.
This is the code of the model in OpenModelica:

```
model Sum
  Modelica.Blocks.Interfaces.RealVectorInput F1[6] annotation(
    Placement(visible = true, transformation(origin = {-72, 78}, extent = {{-20, -20}, {20, 20}}, rotation = 0), iconTransformation(origin = {-72, 74}, extent = {{-14, -14}, {14, 14}}, rotation = 0)));
  Modelica.Blocks.Interfaces.RealVectorInput F2[6] annotation(
    Placement(visible = true, transformation(origin = {-72, 38}, extent = {{-20, -20}, {20, 20}}, rotation = 0), iconTransformation(origin = {-72, 36}, extent = {{-14, -14}, {14, 14}}, rotation = 0)));
  Modelica.Blocks.Interfaces.RealVectorInput F3[6] annotation(
    Placement(visible = true, transformation(origin = {-72, 0}, extent = {{-20, -20}, {20, 20}}, rotation = 0), iconTransformation(origin = {-70, -40}, extent = {{-14, -14}, {14, 14}}, rotation = 0)));
  Modelica.Blocks.Interfaces.RealVectorInput F4[6] annotation(
    Placement(visible = true, transformation(origin = {-70, -44}, extent = {{-20, -20}, {20, 20}}, rotation = 0), iconTransformation(origin = {-68, -80}, extent = {{-14, -14}, {14, 14}}, rotation = 0)));
  Modelica.Blocks.Interfaces.RealVectorOutput SUMF[6] annotation(
    Placement(visible = true, transformation(origin = {76, -4}, extent = {{-20, -20}, {20, 20}}, rotation = 0), iconTransformation(origin = {74, -2}, extent = {{-20, -20}, {20, 20}}, rotation = 0)));
  parameter Real multiply_1=1;
  parameter Real multiply_2=1;
  parameter Real multiply_3=1;
  parameter Real multiply_4=1;
equation
  for i in 1:6 loop
    SUMF[i] = multiply_1*F1[i] + multiply_2*F2[i] + multiply_3*F3[i] + multiply_4*F4[i];
  end for;
  annotation(
    Icon(coordinateSystem(extent = {{-100, -100}, {100, 100}})));
end Sum;
```

Then the FMU is created and this is the code I've used in Python:

```
import sys
import scipy
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import fmpy
from fmpy import *
from matplotlib.backends.backend_agg import FigureCanvasAgg as FigureCanvas

fmu_file = 'Sum.fmu'
model_description = fmpy.read_model_description(fmu_file)
dump(fmu_file)

t_start = 0; t_end = 200; t_step = 0.01

outputs = fmpy.simulate_fmu(
    fmu_file,
    start_time = t_start,
    stop_time = t_end,
    output_interval = t_step,
    input = np.array([1,3,3,3,3,2,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,,0,0,0,0,0,0], dtype=[("F1[1]",np.float64), ("F1[2]",np.float64), ("F1[3]",np.float64), ("F1[4]",np.float64),
                                                                                ("F1[5]",np.float64), ("F1[6]",np.float64), ("F2[1]",np.float64), ("F2[2]",np.float64),
                                                                                ("F2[3]",np.float64), ("F2[4]",np.float64), ("F2[5]",np.float64), ("F2[6]",np.float64),
                                                                                ("F3[1]",np.float64), ("F3[2]",np.float64), ("F3[3]",np.float64), ("F3[4]",np.float64),
                                                                                ("F3[5]",np.float64), ("F3[6]",np.float64), ("F4[1]",np.float64), ("F4[2]",np.float64),
                                                                                ("F4[3]",np.float64), ("F4[4]",np.float64), ("F4[5]",np.float64), ("F4[6]",np.float64)
                                                                                ]),
    output = ('SUMF[1]','SUMF[2]','SUMF[3]','SUMF[4]','SUMF[5]','SUMF[6]'))

time = outputs['time']
timeint = np.logical_not(((np.round(time)-time)/time)!=0)

y = outputs['SUMF[1]'][timeint]


plt.plot(y)
plt.title("y")
plt.xlabel("Time [s]")
plt.ylabel("F")
plt.grid()
plt.show()
```

As always I appreciate very much your help. Thanks :)